# Structure of $i^n \ mod \ p, 1 \leq i <p$ where $p$ is a prime congruent to $3$ mod $4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'd like to ask how to describe the structure of $i^n \ mod \ p, 1 \leq i <p$. Can all the values be constructed using some direct products of some generators? What is the size of the set of values?

Comment: That depends on $i$, I guess? $i$ could be a generator, or it could be $1$. The results vary widely. You should be more specific.

Comment: I mean all the values $1^n \ mod \ p, 2^n \ mod \ p, \cdots, (p-1)^n \ mod \ p$, not a single value.

Comment: This is related to OP's [previous problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2999224/394456).

Comment: Yes. I think there's a structure, but cannot find it exactly.